# What is the purpose of typedefing a class in C++?

Tags: c++, typedef

I've seen code like the following frequently in some C++ code I'm looking at:

```
typedef class SomeClass SomeClass;
```

I'm stumped as to what this actually achieves.  It seems like this wouldn't change anything. What do `typedef`s like this do? And if this does something useful, is it worth the extra effort?

Comment: perhaps you should ask that person? rather than asking everyone but that person.

Comment: I wanted to get a consensus on if it's actually worth it, rather than one person's explanation.

Comment: And the guy actually was wrong. "non-tag hides tag name in C++" - neither true in C, nor true in C++. For some inspiration, read this defect report http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#407

Comment: @litb - Your linked document is quite interesting. But I think it does indicate that there's some merit in what's being done above.  It also points out why it might be that the MS and Digital Mars compilers accept the code snippet in  Adam Rosenfeld's answer below, "... we can conclude that in C++ typedef names do not hide class names declared in the same scope. If they did, the above example would be legal." And it *does* seem to be legal in the MS and DM compilers.

Comment: @Michael, do you say  "typedef class X X; int X;" is accepted by those compilers? I'm not quite following you :)

Comment: @litb - yes that's exactly what happens. And the third example in the document you pointed gives a possible reason why - I wouldn't be surprised if some C code for Windows depends on that behavior, and MS allows it in C++ as an 'extension' for that reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See this previous answer to a related question.  It's a long quote from a Dan Saks article that explains this issue as clearly as anything I've come across:

[Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c/612476#612476)

The technique can prevent actual problems (though admittedly rare problems).

It's a cheap bit of insurance - it's zero cost at runtime or in code space (the only cost is the few bytes in the source file), but the protection you get is so small that it's uncommon to see someone use it consistently.  I have a 'new class' snippet that includes the typedef, but if I actually code up a class from scratch without using the snippet, I almost never bother (or is it remember?) to add the typedef.

So I'd say I disagree with most of the opinions given here - it is worth putting those typedefs in, but not enough that I'd give anyone (including myself) grief about not putting them in.

I've been asked for an example of how not having a class name typedef'ed can result in unexpected behavior - here's an example lifted more or less from the Saks article:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#if 0   // change to #if 1 to get different behavior
        // imagine that this is buried in some header
        // and even worse - it gets added to a header 
        //     during maintenance...
string foo()
{
    return "function foo... \n";
}
#endif

class foo
{
public:
    operator string() {
        return "class foo...\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    string s = foo();

    printf( "%s\n", s.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

When the function declaration is made visible, the behavior of the program silently changes because there is no name conflict between the function `foo` and the class `foo`.

However, if you include a "`typedef class foo foo;`" you'll get a compile time error instead of a silent difference in behavior.

Comment: You have to do so many things wriong for this to happen that I'm tempted to say you deserve it! Number one would be providing conversion casts instead of using named functions (always a no-no, IMHO).

Comment: Conversion operators might be a no-no, but they're not at all uncommon. Anyway, I won't argue the 'so many things have to go wrong' point. Like I said, it's not something I insist on in my or anyone else's code. But I wanted to explain why it's in the OP's code (that was the question after all), and point out that the typedef has no cost and causes no problems. In fact, it makes compilers act a little bit more like people expect - though I was surprised by the behavior of some compilers to Adam's snippet. I think the document linked by litb is educational in that regard.

Comment: That's really interesting; the answers I've gotten to this question make me glad I asked this question on here.

Answer (score 20):

It prevents code like this from compiling:

```
class SomeClass { ... };
int SomeClass;
```

This is perfectly legal C++, though it's *terrible*.  If you do this, then any references to a bare `SomeClass` refer to the variable.  To refer to the class, you need to explicitly say `class SomeClass` at each usage.  If you create a `typedef`:

```
class SomeClass { ... };
typedef class SomeClass SomeClass;
int SomeClass;
```

Then the compiler flags the definition of `int SomeClass` as an error, as it rightly should be.

Comment: Your second example compiles for me (VC2005).

Comment: Problem with VC++ then - it should not compile.

Comment: Interesting, it actually works with one compiler i use (and not with MSVC)

Comment: VC6 compiles it too. If you actually try to *use* it as a class the code blows up of course.

Comment: I tried it with the Comeau online compiler and it failed as desired there. So I guess this must be why it's in the code.  Still seems pointless to me since people should just not write code like that!

Comment: @jpinto I actually had this one marked as correct before, and though it answers why it's done,  it doesn't actually answer if it's worth it.  The makers of SO have said before that the community idea of "best answer" and the asker's idea of "best answer" can be different and that's by design.

Comment: This is interesting - the "typedef class SomeClass SomeClass;" example compiles fine in VC2008, VC6, and Digital Mars (but not in GCC or Comeau).  This seems to clearly be illegal code being accepted by these compilers.  I wonder if there's something in the Windows SDK that makes them accept this as an 'extension'?

Answer (score 6):

Adam has supplied the correct reason for doing this, but regarding your question "Is it worth the trouble" I would give a resounding "No!". The possible problem code:

```
class SomeClass { ... };
int SomeClass;
```

will be caught when a bit later on someone says:

```
SomeClass sc;
```

Admittedly the compiler will point at the "wrong" line, but this sort of thing happens so rarely (I don't think I've ever seen it in real code) that it can't justify a forest of near superfluous typedefs.

Comment: Thanks for answering that question, that's what I really wanted to know. I'd never seen it done before, so I had a feeling it'd not be worth it.

Comment: If you leave out the typedef you may not always get an error, though admittedly the situations would be rare.  A function with the same name as a class can hide something that would otherwise be a class constructor.

Comment: Could you post an example of this - I can't visualise how it would be possible.

Comment: Neil - see my updated answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/953166/what-is-the-purpose-of-typedefing-a-class-in-c/954445#954445

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the comment is trying to say that the typedef makes the symbol SomeClass global in a way that prevents anybody from being able to declare a local object with the same name that hides the original SomeClass.

I tried this out with VC6 (not a real C++ compiler I know, but the best I have ATM), and it doesn't seem to do much. SomeClass still gets hidden by a local declaration with the same name. Perhaps it changes the content of an error message for some compiler to make it more useful.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your colleague may not have fully graduated from C.

In C, if you declare `struct foo {int a;};`, you don't have anything you can call just `foo`, but rather `struct foo`.  Therefore, it's fairly common to typedef `struct foo` as `foo`.

This was changed in C++, for reasons that should be fairly obvious.

Comment: It's possible, but I wouldn't really call C's behavior "name hiding."

Answer (score 0):

Either really broken compiler or someone not knowing what they do, or so I would think.

Answer (score -2):

> I understand the concept of the
>   different namespaces that tags and
>   identifiers live in, but is this
>   really even worth the trouble of
>   typing it?

No.

Comment: (-1) Absolutely no explanation or reasoning. I could just as easily have written "Yes." and the only difference would have been reputation.

Comment: You don't like my answer (he, after all, laid out the reasoning), write your own.